# Потрфель Windows - хуже Вируса!

Tags: windows-7

Доброго всем времени.Когда-то, давным давно, когда были времена flash'ек, я занимался синхронизацией 2-х ПК через один flash-накопитель.
Прошло лет 5-6 с тех пор, нет тех компьютеров, нет той флэшки (утеряна со всеми новыми наработками...) И синхронизация тут не поможет... Даже ОСь уже не та...
Так вот, как теперь удалить портфель?
Т.е. я отрываю этот запортфеленный каталог, он постоянно пишет невозможно открыть, он используется другими кем-то... или чем-то.
вижу в каталоге есть файл - "Briefcase Database", хочу его убить... Но он не убиваем!!!Неужели что бы убить свойства портфеля надо запускаться с альтернативной ОСью?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Через столько лет нашлось решение.
удалил в каталоге `desktop.ini` и всё решилось.
Т.е. привязка-ассоциация с "Портфелем" была прописана именно в нём.
*P.S. А ведь сколько лет он меня мучил!*

Comment: Поздравляю Вас!

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, портфель выделен в области переходов (левая панель в окне Проводника).решение - перетащить портфель на раб. стол, затем удалить его.